# Playa parent ids automatically shows future entries ids

Tags: playa

I noticed that `{exp:playa:parent_ids}` returns the parent ids, even if that parent's entry date is in the future.
Isn't it confusing to change the way EE works with future entries?

**support answer:**

*_ids tags currently don't support the show_future_entries parameter.

There's an upside, though - we are releasing a new Playa version today and this will be fixed in that, so you'll have your issues fixed with the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playa tag supports almost all of EE's channel entry tag parameters out of the box so if you wanted to [not show future entries](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#show-future-entries) then you just need to add that as a parameter:

```
{exp:playa:parent_ids show_future_entries="no"}
```

Comment: I understand that I can put the parameter to "no", I was just wondering why it's on "yes", it was confusing because `{exp:playa:parents}` doesn't use the show_future_entries="yes" as default.

Comment: So `{exp:playa:parents}` doesn't display future entries and `{exp:playa:parent_ids}` does by default? By default EE doesn't show entries who's date is in the future so if that's the case it could be a bug. Can you confirm that is the case?

Comment: That is indeed the case

Comment: If it is a bug then the best bet would be to highlight it as such to the P&T guys who will be able to confirm or provide a fix. Although I can't think of why there may be a good reason while this deviates from regular EE behaviour for this tag.